# How to access new charts in Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I want to access the new charts added in MS Office 2016, specificly the waterfall chart, through VBA.

I recorded a macro while adding it manually, but the macro does not seem to recognize the chart type.

Comment: It's just `xlWaterfall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using MS 2016, but I think one way you could find the chart type for future use would be to place a waterfall chart on a sheet and then run a quick sub that returns the `Chart.ChartType` for each chart on the sheet.  That should return an integer value which can then be used to set other charts to that type.  the code should be something like:

```
MsgBox(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartType)
```

Comment: You should also find all ChartTypes under https://msdn.microsoft.com/us-en/library/office/ff838409.aspx#

Comment: @Tom I checked there first, but it doesn't seem to display a value for the "waterfall" chart referenced by OP.  My guess is that the enumeration hasn't been updated yet to include additions to the 2016 edition, in which case this code should find the type.

Comment: It's still not listed at the Microsoft page, but if you look in the VBIDE Object Browser under XlChartType, you can find all of the new chart types, including xlWaterfall.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Office 365 Insider build, the macro recorder is aware of waterfall charts. Here is code recorded while I added a waterfall chart and set three of the bars to totals:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(395, xlWaterfall).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(1).IsTotal = True
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(4).IsTotal = True
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(7).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(7).IsTotal = True
    Application.CommandBars("Accessibility").Visible = False
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Note that there are many features of the new charts, including waterfalls, which cannot be accessed with VBA, and even with the regular user interface. For example, you can set the vertical axis minimum and maximum, but not the major unit (the tick spacing).